# Writing the formula for surface area of a rectangular pyramid in C#

Tags: c#, math

I need help in writing the formula for the total surface area of a rectangular pyramid. This is the formula I want to write in C#:

[image]

This is what I have so far and I've tried various variations(like using Math.Pow etc.) of it but still no progress:

```
 resultPyramidArea = "Pyramid area: " + (length3d * width3d + length3d) * Math.Sqrt(((width3d / 2.000) * (width3d / 2.000)) + (height3d * height3d)) + width3d * Math.Sqrt(((length3d / 2.000) * (length3d * 2.000)) + (height3d * height3d));
```

In the formula, A is Area, l is replaced with length3d, w with width3d and h with height3d

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a good opportunity to break apart the equation into smaller pieces.  Each individual calculation can be placed in its own variable and then used in the next step of the calculation.  Basically, there's no reason why this needs to all be on one line.  When you separate it out into individual calculations, which one fails?  What is the expected result vs. the actual result?

Comment: Pay attention to your order of operations.

Comment: Really? A single line of code that's almost 240 characters long? You know, you can split a statement across lines so you don't have to scroll horizontally. As a benefit, you can then see the entire expression at once. For the love of your sanity and everybody else's, please reformat that code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your order of operations is incorrect. It should be this:

```
resultPyramidArea = 
      (length3d * width3d) 
    + (length3d * Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(width3d / 2, 2) + Math.Pow(height3d, 2))) 
    + (width3d * Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(length3d / 2, 2) + Math.Pow(height3d, 2)));
```

Edit: Code I used to test this statement for you OP:

```
static void Main()
    {
        double length3d = 4;
        double width3d = 2;
        double height3d = 3;
        double resultPyramidArea = (length3d * width3d) + (length3d * Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(width3d / 2, 2) + Math.Pow(height3d, 2))) + (width3d * Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(length3d / 2, 2) + Math.Pow(height3d, 2)));
        Console.WriteLine(resultPyramidArea);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

It's correct, I tried the inputs on google's online calculator and got the correct answer. If you are still having problems its probably because in your original code `resultPyramidArea` is adding a string and a double, **This is not a valid statement in C# if resultPyramidArea is a double type variable** , if you want to display the "Pyramid area: " message, do this instead:

```
Console.WriteLine("Pyramid area: {0}", resultPyramidArea)
```

with resultPyramidArea just being a double

Comment: Still not working :/ I use the google calculator when you search for "Caclulate area of a pyramid" to check if my code is correct

Comment: Hmm I tried that formula in a console application and it worked perfectly. Must be somewhere else in my code then, because it gives me this impossibly huge number starting with 812,649, this calculation is done in a class I made for all the different shape calculations. Everything else so far works except for this surface area. Even the Pyramid Volume works fine. I don't even know anymore, since they use the same inputs,  the volume and area

Comment: @GerritBotes Utilize this corrected calculation in your surface area function and it should work fine, I can't imagine the functions you're writing for your class are interfering with each other that much. If you want, post your class definition and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I know my code is a huge mess and could be greatly improved but I'm just trying to make this quick app, I'm still new and still learning. Here is the code I use to output the Pyramid volume and surface to labels https://pastebin.com/kdTmM72C And here is a paste of the entire class: https://pastebin.com/rfWb9ZaX

Comment: @GerritBotes I don't see anything wrong in the code you pasted, granted I'm not seeing any of your function definitions or anything but they seem simple enough based on their names. Keep working on it yourself and if you still can't seem to get anywhere ping me in these comments and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: @GerritBotes In terms of math the two pastes you posted are correct, I don't have much experience with winforms but those seem to be set up correctly as well, are you still experiencing an issue?

Comment: Yes finally got it to work after just brute forcing the code until it worked. I ended up adding new variables and adding the calculation to the form instead of the class specifically just for the Pyramid area. It's really messy now but idc as long as it is working for the time being. I don't want to be spending too much time on this project. Thanks so much for all the help I really appreciate it. Here is the new code in the form: https://pastebin.com/TwJiJ72i

Comment: @GerritBotes No problem, would you mind marking this question as answered while you're at it? Both answers should have sufficiently solved your problem, whichever you pick is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
double length3d = 10;
double width3d = 10;
double height3d = 10;

double slant1 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(width3d / 2, 2) + Math.Pow(height3d, 2));
double slant2 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(length3d / 2, 2) + Math.Pow(height3d, 2));

resultPyramidArea = (length3d * width3d) + (length3d * slant1) + (width3d * slant2);
// Output: 323.60679774997897
```

EDIT: Adding comparison of results with google for OP

**Output from Google**

[image]

Comment: Not working :/ To see if my program gives the correct answer I reference it with the answer google's calculator gives me when you search "calculate area of a pyramid"

Comment: @GerritBotes it seems to be working fine. Updated the answer with comparison with Google's result. Please note that formula and all discussion is for a *Right Rectangular Pyramid* like you mentioned.

Comment: Yeah the formula seems to be fine, it must be something else with my code, sorting that out now. Thanks so much for the help.